# Tag <ErrorMessage> Formik react Style

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, formik

I would like to apply the style to Formik's  tag for react. How can I do?

`<ErrorMessage name="email"></ErrorMessage>`

I try with component={Custom} but don't work.

I use Tailwindcss.

Thanks if you want to help me.

Comment: Have you tried just using a ```style``` prop?

Comment: No...I try to use style prop. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method worked for me in react..

```
<ErrorMessage name='email' render={msg => <div className="error">{msg}</div>}/>
```

then, call that className in the CSS file

```
.error{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: just make sure that `.error` is not reserved as in bootsrap or any others CSS framework

Answer (score 14):

To [add a class](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) to a React component, use `className="theClass"`. Formik's [ErrorMessage.component](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/errormessage#component) property takes a value of a custom component, e.g. `component={Custom}` as you have, or it can take an HTML container, e.g. `component="div"`. Assuming this is not a Tailwind port to React, "div" is appropriate. Putting these two together, you can apply [Tailwind-style invalid message](https://tailwindcss.com/components/forms) styling thus:

```
<ErrorMessage name="emailAddress" component="div" className="text-red-500 text-xs italic" />
```

Comment: Thank you - worked perfectly when added the div.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ErrorMessage name="field name" component="div" className="some classes" />
```

add "component" field for ErrorMessage component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).